# nested DIVS do not "see" overflow content

Tags: html, css, overflow, z-index

Alright, so I am trying to make a navigation bar for a website, but there are a lot of links - so much so that on mobile sizing you need to be able to scroll. The problem is that it doesn't see the rest of the content of the middle div.

The set up is as follows:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="nav-link-holder inactive">
 <div class="nav-link nav-link-style" data-target="category-div-1">TITLE OF LINK</div>
 <div class="nav-div inactive" id="category-div-1">
   <div class="list-group">
     <div class="list">LIST OF LINKS</div>
   </div>
   <div class="list-group">
     <div class="list">LIST OF LINKS</div>
   </div>
   <div class="list-group">
     <div class="list">LIST OF LINKS</div>
   </div>
  </div> <!--closes NAV-DIV -->
  <div class="nav-link nav-link-style" data-target="category-div-2">TITLE OF LINK</div>
  <div class="nav-div inactive" id="category-div-2">
   <div class="list-group">
     <div class="list">LIST OF LINKS</div>
   </div>
   <div class="list-group">
     <div class="list">LIST OF LINKS</div>
   </div>
   <div class="list-group">
     <div class="list">LIST OF LINKS</div>
   </div>
  </div> <!--closes NAV-DIV -->
</div> <!-- closes the holder -->
```

The problem with so many nested divs is that when one overflows over the other, it doesn't see the content. So if the combined content of "LIST OF LINKS" is longer than the device height, then it needs to be able to scroll down. I can make a scrollbar appear on the nav-div with the css, but it is not active, so I assume it cannot see the content.

**CSS:**

```
.nav-link-holder {
   width: 100%;
   position: fixed;
   top: 60px;
   left: 0;
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
   z-index: 8100;
}
.nav-link-style {
   display: inline-block;
   position: relative;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 60px;
   text-align: center;
   background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .9);
   cursor: pointer;
   font-size: 15px;
   padding: 0 !important;
   z-index: 8100;
}
.nav-div {
   width: 100%;
   position: relative;
   padding: 5px 0 10px 0;
   margin: 0;
   background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .9);
   overflow-y: scroll;
   text-align: center;
   z-index: 8500;
}
.list-group {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
}

.list {
    width: 300px;
    position: relative;
    height: auto;
    padding: 5px 15px 15px 15px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}
```

All the divs with data-targets are links that expand the nav-divs using javascript that adds an active and inactive class (affects just the display property). When the nav-div expands on mobile it is too long for the height. How do I get it to scroll the nav-div container when the inner divs exceed the "holder" height?
Here is a codepen that I was using as the first draft - it has the same problem when you click "catagory 1" and reduce the with to less than 400px: http://codepen.io/ebevers/pen/PqybBb

Comment: Please add a Fiddle or something similar that reproduces the problem.

Comment: I added the codepen I made as a first draft.

Comment: I figured it out. I was adding the scroll to the parent div of the one with overflow. I need to add it to the list-group div.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add the overflow-y: scroll to the parent of the divs that were causing the overflow - in this case it was the list-group div.